# Obtener indice que ocupa un item en array bidimensional

Tags: c#, array

Recorriendo un array bidimensional con un foreach ,me gustaría poder cambiar el valor de un ítem de este, pero no sé como obtener el índice de este 
ítem[x,y].

```
   public string[,] Emplena(string[,] caixa)
    {
        foreach (string lletra in caixa)
        {
            if (lletra == "Y")
            {
                caixa[x,y] = " ";
            }
        }

        return caixa;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Con el `foreach` no podrás modificar el contenido de la matriz. Necesitas usar un bucle anidado para recorrer cada fila y columna de la matriz, de ese modo, lograrás asignar un objeto en una determinada columna.

Por ejemplo:

```
public string[,] Emplena(int rows, int cols, string[,] caixa)
    {
        int i, j;
        for(i = 0; i != rows; ++i)
        {
            for(j = 0; j != cols; ++j)
            {
                if (caixa[i, j] == "Y")
                    caixa[i, j] = " ";
            }
        }
        return caixa;
    }
```

**Modo de uso:**

```
    static void Main()
    {
        int i, j;
        string[,] caixa = new string[2, 2]
        {
            {"Y", "X"},
            {"Z", "Y"}
        };
        Emplena(2, 2, caixa);
        for(i = 0; i != 2; ++i)
        {
            for(j = 0; j != 2; ++j)
                Console.Write(caixa[i, j]);
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

El resultado en pantalla es:

```
[space] X //Fila 1
Z       [space] //Fila 2
```

Comment: Lo entiendo, pero a lo que me refería, mas que a modificar el contenido del ítem, era a obtener su posición en la matriz. Pero entiendo por tu respuesta, que no hay ningún método que me retorne tal dato. Gracias.